# Why is magick giving an error while converting base64 files?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of base64 encoded images which I want to convert to their corresponding image files using magick (ImageMagick version 7). I can paste the base64 directly into various online converters which works. But command-line magick is failing.

Example of a file is attached in "x.txt". Pasting it into an online converter like https://onlinejpgtools.com/convert-base64-to-jpg readily yields an image. But this command line fails:

```
magick inline:`cat x.txt` x.png
```

This says "magick: corrupt image". If I remove the "inline" part, I get "magick: unable to open image". Here is a link to download the  [sample file x.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0ti35xi1xdwqgo/x.txt?dl=0):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, try (no cat). That works for me.

```
magick inline:x.txt x.png
```

[image]

Or pipe from cat to magick as

```
cat tmp.txt | magick inline:- y.png
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I had tried "magick x.txt x.png" but that didn't work. I needed the "inline:" on the file name. Thanks!